# log... 4... tag... What is it good4? Absolutely nothing

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

I just came across the [log4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log4) tag. Someone had used it rather than [log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log4j). It has no usage guidance or description.

There are 68 questions. It doesn't seem to unambiguously refer to anything that actually exists. The vast majority look like typos that should have been tagged with [log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log4j).

A couple are tagged with [log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log4net) and [log4cxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log4cxx). Perhaps tag this was created to cover all log4___ libraries, but these are distinct libraries maintained by different people with nothing in common besides the same broad purpose. I don't see the value in keeping it for that reason. It doesn't seem to ever have been used in that way and even with usage guidance to this effect it still wouldn't be.

Let's get rid?

Answer (score 10):

I agree; going through the list of questions, this looks like a clear case of "someone didn't type out the full tag before hitting enter" and then 67 more people were guilty of the same laziness.

NB - there were a couple questions referring to [log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log4net) for C#; I've gone ahead and edited those.

Comment: Totally unforgivabl

Comment: If you get it to a point that all remaining questions with [log4] are about [log4j], let me know so I can one-click merge. No reason to manually retag all those.

Comment: @CodyGray All the remaining [tag:log4] questions refer to [tag:log4j], with the exception of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296079/javascript-ajax-remote-logger) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452510/whats-your-favorite-log4-viewer-monitor) which are both tool requests and can probably be deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Tag merge completed.

Comment: Improbabl, but not impossibl.

Comment: @CodyGray Didn't notice this til now. Thanks cody

Comment: Absolutely, totally, and in all other ways inconceivabl!